# How to convert array into comma separated string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

`a.value =  [a,b,c,d,e,f]`

How can I convert to comma seperated string like

`a.value = "a,b,c,d,e,f"`

Thanks for all help.

Comment: `a.value = a.value.join()`

Comment: `Array.toString()` returns comma seperated string by default

Comment: You can use  `let comma_seprated = a.value.join()` or `let comma_seprated = a.value.join(", ")`

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The method `array.toString()` actually calls `array.join()` which result in a string concatenated by commas. [ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2)

```js
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
document.write(array.toString()); // "a,b,c,d,e,f"
```

Also, you can implicitly call `Array.toString()` by making javascript coerce the `Array` to an `string`, like:

```
//will implicitly call array.toString()
str = ""+array;
str = `${array}`;
```

---

## Array.prototype.join()

The [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method joins all elements of an array into a string.

#### Arguments:

It accepts a `separator` as argument, but the default is already a comma `,`

```
str = arr.join([separator = ','])
```

#### Examples:

```
var array = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var myVar1 = array.join();      // 'A,B,C'
var myVar2 = array.join(', ');  // 'A, B, C'
var myVar3 = array.join(' + '); // 'A + B + C'
var myVar4 = array.join('');    // 'ABC'
```

#### Note:

> If any element of the array is undefined or null , it is treated as an empty string.

#### Browser support:

It is available pretty much everywhere today, since IE 5.5 (1999~2000).

#### References

- [ECMA Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5)
- [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/59x7k999(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 42):

Use the [`join` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) from the Array type.

```
a.value = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
var stringValueYouWant = a.join();
```

The `join` method will return a string that is the concatenation of all the array elements. It will use the first parameter you pass as a separator - if you don't use one, it will use the default separator, which is the comma.

Comment: This is the right answer here!

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use JavaScripts `join()` function for that. This would simply look like `a.value.join(',')`. The output would be a string though.