# React, display a customized array in the return of the main function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function, return

I have a react project with the home.jsx file where I create an array of JSON:

```
function Home() {
  const posts = [
    {
      id:1,
      title:"Point Break",
      year:"1992",
      category:["Action","Hold-up","Crime","Surfing","Cult Movie"],
      description:"The film features Reeves as an undercover FBI agent....",
      image: "/movies/1.png"
    },{..}
//etc..
```

Then in the return of the home function I render that list like that:

```
return (
posts.map(
          post=>(
            <div className="post" key={ post.id}>
              <div className="img">
              </div>
              <div className="content">
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>         
                <p>Category: 
                  {  
                    post.category.map( element =>( element+", "))
                  }</p>                  
                <p>{post.description}</p>                    
              </div>                 
            </div>
))}
```

The problem comes when I want to render the category key with its array, with a comma between the words but not the last, because there is no word after that
The output looks like that

[image: Output]

I want to avoid the last comma in the image, but apparently I cannot create any logic in the return. How can I achieve this? Do I need to make a function outside the return?

I already tried something like that:

```
  const filterCommas = (list,listlength) => {
    var $i=0;
    var renderlist=""
    list.forEach(element => {
      if($i<=listlength-1){
        renderlist += element + ", "
      }
      $i+=1;
    });
    return filteredList;
  }
```

But I cannot call it from the return function. How can I filter the commas?

Comment: have you tried to use `slice` to remove the latest character?

Comment: simply `post.category.join(", ")` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771183/13583510

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer Rohad. I tried (post.category.map( element =>( element+", "))).slice(0,-1) but actually it cuts the last element of the list :(. Actually there is a nooed to be able to put logic inside the render to remove the comma XD. I m gonna try other options but thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. Post.category.join is perfect :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok so cmgchess (Thanks a lot :)) gave me the answer which is:

`> post.category.join(", ")` inside the return:

So I would have:

```
<p>
    Category: {  
        post.category.join(", ")
    }
</p>
```

Instead of:

```
<p>
    Category: {  
        post.category.map( element =>( element+", "))
    }
</p>
```

Thanks for that :).

Still if there are other methods, I would be glad to hear because sometimes there is a need to be able to filter some informations with some logic (maybe a variable or a loop somewhere). Thanks